# React JS. All user objects on the page disappears even though a single user is unfollowed while clicking the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Hi guys I am new to react js, I have this code to unfollow users from a list, the code is working, the the selected user is followed when the button is clicked, but the problem is all the users disappear when I click the unfollow button and I have to refresh the page to see the other users in the list. How to properly do it? I am not able to understand what I did wrong in the code.

I want it to work normal, as when we click the button adjacent to a specific user, only that user should disappear from the list instead of all users.

Please do take a look at the code.

```
const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

const [followUsers, setfollowUsers] = useState([]); 

function unfollowUser(otherUser, index) {
    const updatedUsers = [...followUsers.results];
    console.log([updatedUsers[index]]);
    updatedUsers[index] = [updatedUsers[index]].filter(x => x.id !== user.id);
    setfollowUsers(updatedUsers);
    unfollowUserfunction("delete", otherUser);
}

async function unfollowUserfunction(method, otherUser) {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.request("/profile/" + otherUser.username + '/unfollow/', { method });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}



{followUsers.results && followUsers.results.map((otherUser, index) => {
   return (
      <div className="searchRows" key={otherUser.id}>
            <div className="searchRows__username">
               <p>{otherUser.username}</p>
            </div> 
         </div>
      </div>
      <div className="user__right">        
          <Tooltip title="unfollow">
            <CheckIcon className="search__unfollow_icon"
               onClick={() => {
                 unfollowUser(otherUser, index)
               }}
            />
         </Tooltip>
     </div>
  </div>
)
  })
}
```

The response of `followUsers` from the console.

```
{count: 2, next: null, previous: null, results: Array(2)}
count: 2
next: null
previous: null
results: Array(2)
0: {id: 3, username: "tester1", full_name: "Test1", profile_pic: "/media/pimage/default.png"}
1: {id: 4, username: "tester2", full_name: "Test2", profile_pic: "/media/pimage/default.png"}
length: 2
```

What can be the reason for the disappearance of all users while I click the button? Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [...followUsers.results] should [...followUsers] maybe ? why do you use .results there ?

Comment: I am using django drf in the backend..so if we give pagination, the exact data we want will be inside results object.

Comment: Do you see the correct value in console.log ?

Comment: Yes. I can see the correct values.

Comment: I will update the question with the response I get from the console now. Please do have a look at it.

Comment: Can you check my answer :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your followers is an object, and you set it with an array

```
function unfollowUser(otherUser, index) {
    const updatedUsers = [...followUsers.results];
    console.log([updatedUsers[index]]);
    updatedUsers[index] = [updatedUsers[index]].filter(x => x.id !== user.id);
    // an array is set to followers
    setfollowUsers(updatedUsers);
    unfollowUserfunction("delete", otherUser);
}
```

So followers.result is undefined thats why you are seeing the empty screen.

Try this code, this will replace the results property so that the UI will be updated properly

```
function unfollowUser(otherUser, index) {
    const updatedUsers = [...followUsers.results];
    console.log([updatedUsers[index]]);
    updatedUsers[index] = [updatedUsers[index]].filter(x => x.id !== user.id);
    // an array is set to followers
    setfollowUsers(Object.assign({},followUsers,{results:updatedUsers}));
    unfollowUserfunction("delete", otherUser);
}
```

Comment: Hii, I will check it out. but is it followers or followUsers, I am quite confused there. Thanks :)

Comment: sorry followUsers

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly.
Thank you for the answer and the explanation. :)